# UIScrollView improperly loading images (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiimage

I am using a static table in iOS8, with an image scroller in one of the cells. I have encountered a problem that when the page is loaded and the image scroller is not on the initially loaded view, the images are loaded incorrectly in the view.

(I dont have enough reputation to post images, but it can be viewed here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qya4rwfe4dd3ryl/Screenshot%202015-05-14%2017.34.38.png?dl=0)

However, when the image scroller is loaded in the initial view, they are formatted correctly (https://www.dropbox.com/s/euwmxtvsl2yqbaz/Screenshot%202015-05-14%2017.35.41.png?dl=0)

My Code is Thus:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })

}
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    pageImages = [UIImage(named: "photo1.png")!,
        UIImage(named: "photo2.png")!,
        UIImage(named: "photo3.png")!,
        UIImage(named: "photo4.png")!,
        UIImage(named: "photo5.png")!]

    let pageCount = pageImages.count


    for _ in 0..<pageCount {
        pageViews.append(nil)
    }

    let pagesScrollViewSize = scrollView.frame
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(pagesScrollViewSize.width * CGFloat(pageImages.count), pagesScrollViewSize.height)

    self.loadVisiblePages()


}
```

When `loadVisiblePages()` method loads the pages that should currently be in the scroll view (extra code below)
I have to put the `tableView.reloadData()` in the main queue so the label can resize properly.

Would love any suggestions or help anyone can offer.
Thanks in advance

```
func loadVisiblePages() {

    // First, determine which page is currently visible
    let pageWidth = scrollView.frame.size.width
    let page = Int(floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x * 2 + pageWidth) / (pageWidth * 2.0)))


    // Work out which pages you want to load
    let firstPage = max(0,page - 1)
    let lastPage = min(page + 1, pageImages.count - 1)

    // Purge anything before the first page
    for index in 0..<firstPage {
        purgePage(index)
    }

    // Load pages in our range
    for index in firstPage...lastPage {
        loadPage(index)
    }

    // Purge anything after the last page
    for index in (lastPage + 1)..<(pageImages.count) {
        purgePage(index)
    }
}

func loadPage(page: Int) {
    if page < 0 || page >= pageImages.count {
        // If it's outside the range of what you have to display, then do nothing
        return
    }

    // Load an individual page, first checking if you've already loaded it
    if let pageView = pageViews[page] {
        // Do nothing. The view is already loaded.
    } else {
        var frame = scrollView.bounds
        frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * CGFloat(page)
        frame.origin.y = 0.0
        frame = CGRectInset(frame, 10.0, 0.0)

        let newPageView = UIImageView(image: pageImages[page])
        newPageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
        newPageView.frame = frame
        scrollView.addSubview(newPageView)
        pageViews[page] = newPageView
    }
}

func purgePage(page: Int) {
    if page < 0 || page >= pageImages.count {
        // If it's outside the range of what you have to display, then do nothing
        return
    }

    // Remove a page from the scroll view and reset the container array
    if let pageView = pageViews[page] {
        pageView.removeFromSuperview()
        pageViews[page] = nil
    }
}

override func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    // Load the pages that are now on screen
    self.loadVisiblePages()
}
```

Comment: It might be easier for if you used the iCarousel library.